# comparison operator in a column with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Sample dataframe :

```
R_no.    Score

101       10
102       15
103       Nan
104       Nan
105       9
```

If the score is less than 15 return fail, if Nan then return Not attempted else pass.
The output should get in another column of a dataframe.

Required output:

```
R_no.    Score      result  
101       10         fail
102       15         pass    
103       Nan        not attempted
104       Nan        not attempted
105       9          fail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or alternatively, [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
# Replace Nan to np.nan
df.replace('Nan',np.nan,inplace=True)

# Assign fail/pass/not attempted
df['result'] = np.where(df['Score'] < 15,'fail',
                        np.where(df['Score'].isnull(),"not attempted",'pass'))
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to use `numpy`, you could use indexing, with `.loc`:

```
df.loc[(df['Score']<15),'result'] = 'fail'
df.loc[(df['Score'].isnull()),'result'] = 'not attempted'
df['result'].fillna('pass',inplace=True)
```

Prints:

```
   R_no.  Score         result
0    101   10.0           fail
1    102   15.0           pass
2    103    NaN  not attempted
3    104    NaN  not attempted
4    105    9.0           fail
```

Comment: how can we to do without using numpy?

Comment: I updated my answer. You could use ```loc``` if you don't want to use ```numpy```.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with convert column to numeric, because seems in sample data are strings `Nan` (which are converted to missing values):

```
df['Score'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Score'], errors='coerce')

df['res'] = np.select([df.Score < 15, df.Score >= 15], 
                      ['fail','pass'],
                      default='not attempted')

print (df)
   R_no.  Score            res
0    101   10.0           fail
1    102   15.0           pass
2    103    NaN  not attempted
3    104    NaN  not attempted
4    105    9.0           fail
```

Comment: how can we to do without using numpy? @jezrael